# Можно ли сказать "здание начнёт работу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Хочу заменить фразу "здание откроется" на "здание начнёт работу". Верен ли второй вариант?

Answer (score 2):

Здание откроется, а учреждения, расположенные  в нем, откроются или начнут работу.

Например: На территории Новой Москвы открылось новое здание многофункционального миграционного центра. Музей истории ГУЛАГа начал работать в Москве в новом здании.

Answer (score 1):

Здание, в общем случае — безличное, — может быть **готовым** и может **начать функционировать**. При указании хозяйствующей фирмы или назначения (здание ГО, здание ТЦ), кроме здания жилого, может начать работать.

Форма «здание откроется» без уточнения для чего, после чего (для приёма, после ремонта), — неверна, т.к. не полная.

Answer (score 0):

Да, такой верен. Это т. н. прием метонимии. Ср. примеры из интернета.

> Здание мэрии начало работу 15 июля 2002 года, а официальная церемония открытия состоялась 23 июля 2002 года **(Красноярский журнал
>   о новостройках, дизайне и строительстве).**
>
> На Юго-востоке Эстонии начало работу новое современное здание кордона Пиуза **(Новости - Nordecon).**
>
> Здание Товарно-фондовой биржи начнет свою работу, несмотря на решение градостроительного совета, сообщил журналистам президент холдинга "Эталон-ЛенСпецСМУ" Вячеслав Заренков **(Санкт-Петербург.ру)**
>
> В тестовом режиме здание начнет работать уже с 1 сентября **(КАРЕЛИЯ N 58 (2408) за 30 июля 2013 года).**

Comment: Ужас. А ничего, что примеры все за уши притянутые? Контекст - наше всею.

Answer (score 0):

Здание начнёт работу? — Ни в коем случае. Метонимия метонимией, но не до такой же степени. Ссылки на всякие там газеты совершенно не убеждают.

Comment: Но тогда хоть приведите контр аргументы. Ваше "ни в коем случае" то же совершенно не убеждает. Написать "так нельзя" все могут.

Answer (score 0):

> Хочу заменить фразу "здание откроется" на "здание начнёт работу".
>   Верен ли второй вариант?

Если имеется в виду, что это здание, в котором расположены какие-то предприятия, магазины и т.п. - и они, именно они, **начинают работу**, то оба варианта не совсем верны. Но второй просто плох, тут Sibylla права, в этом случае **здание** именно открывается (для доступа), но вряд ли работает. "Метонимия" не прокатывает, ибо смысл нарушается.

Но что мне не нравится у всех уже отметившихся, так это то, что идут рекомендации без уточнения контекста. А он здесь важен.

1) Метонимия ("здание начнет работу") вполне возможна, если скажем, здание это отдельных цех или, скажем, строящаяся насосная станция. В таком случае здание вполне может "работать". насосы запустили - *здание* работает.
2) Если по каким-то причинам здание "начинает работу" позже или раньше подобных ему или рядом стоящих, то почему нет?
Это  для примера. Можно еще придумать. Другое дело, что подобные примеры все малоактуальные.